How can we neglect fluctuations in the Ising model with mean field approximation?
In the Ising model, mean field approximation consists in writing each spin $S_i$ as a fluctuation around its average value and neglect this fluctuation:
\begin{equation}
S_i=\overline S +\delta S_i \quad \text{with}\quad |\delta S_i| \ll |\overline S|
\end{equation}
where the average value can be taken either over time, or over all $N$ spins, thanks to the ergodicity hypothesis.
I don't understand how we can neglect these fluctuations $\delta S_i$.
For example, in the paramagnetic phase, I guess the average value is zero $\overline S=0$.
And as the spin is quantized $S_i=\pm 1$, the fluctuation must be $\delta S_i=\pm 1$ which is never small compared to $\overline S$.
What am I missing ?

You cannot ignore the fluctuations. That's why it's an approxmation.
Only when the system is such that every spin interacts equally with the every other spin ---  no matter how far away it is  --- and there are infinitely many spins --- is mean-field exact.
It's just the first and simplest guide to what is going on. It often fails abysmally.

In mean field approximation, "neglecting fluctuations" does not mean that their size is small compared with the average value of the corresponding average observable. It means that the effect of fluctuations on thermodynamic behavior can be assumed to be small and neglected as a reasonable first approximation.
Unfortunately, sometimes, we find statements that seem to imply inequalities like $|\delta S| \ll |\bar S |$, but they are not consistent and not required by the mean-field approximation.

Okay, I understand now, we actually neglect $\sum_{(i,j)} \delta S_i \delta S_j$ in the Hamiltonian, and not really each $\delta S_i$. That makes a little more sense.
